# step by step process of installation of moodle

Tags: moodle

can you provide detailed information about moodle open source community.I googled, but iam not getting information fully.I downloaded the zip folder while opening in my localhost it gives error.

```
Warning: Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in D:\xampp\htdocs\moodle\index.php on line 218
```

I want how to install and how to check it in localhost 
plz help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this link for downloading moodle and latest version

https://download.moodle.org/releases/latest/

its may be helpful to you

Answer (score 1):

Step by step installation instructions

https://docs.moodle.org/29/en/Installing_Moodle

Answer (score 0):

The error that you quoted appears when you try to install Moodle on the very-very old version of PHP - it does not know how to work with namespaces and fails even before performing environment check.

Please check requirements for the Moodle version you are installing and upgrade your PHP.

If you want, you can vote on the issue when people complain about confusing error message:
https://tracker.moodle.org/browse/MDL-44276

Comment: By the way, you can download complete XAMPP package to install Moodle on Windows - it will include PHP with all required modules and all versions will be correct. See https://download.moodle.org/windows/ - this will save you lots of time!

Answer (score 0):

1. Step 1. 
       Download this File. 
       https://download.moodle.org/download.php/stable34/moodle-latest-34.zip
2. Step 2. 
       Unzip this folder and paste it in this directory. 
       **C:\Xampp\htdocs**
3. Step 3.
        Open the web browser and type this
       **localhost/moodle/index.php**
4. Step 4.
        **1st create sample database in phpMyAdmin Like sample_db** before you provide the name
       Just click on next and provide database same
5. Step 5.
        configure your **php.ini** file **C:\Xampp\php\php.ini**
         Remove the comment **";"** form the following

   ```
   ;zend.enable_gc=On  
   ;extension=php_intl.dll  
   ;extension=php_soap.dll  
   ;extension=php_xmlrpc.dll
   ```
6. Step 6.
        Copy and Paste this code in  **php.ini** file **C:\Xampp\php\php.ini**

   ```
    zend_extension=C:\xampp\php\ext\php_opcache.dll  
    [opcache]  
    opcache.enable = 1   
    opcache.memory_consumption = 128  
    opcache.max_accelerated_files = 4000  
    opcache.revalidate_freq = 60 

   ; Required for Moodle  
   opcache.use_cwd = 1  
   opcache.validate_timestamps = 1  
   opcache.save_comments = 1  
   opcache.enable_file_override = 0  

   ; If something does not work in Moodle  
   ;opcache.revalidate_path = 1 ; May fix problems with include paths  
   ;opcache.mmap_base = 0x20000000 ; (Windows only) fix OPcache crashes with event id 487  

   ; Experimental for Moodle 2.6 and later  
   ;opcache.fast_shutdown = 1  
   ;opcache.enable_cli = 1 ; Speeds up CLI cron  
   ;opcache.load_comments = 0 ; May lower memory use, might not be compatible with add-ons and other apps  

   extension=C:\xampp\php\ext\php_intl.dll  

   [intl]  
   intl.default_locale = en_utf8  
   intl.error_level = E_WARNING
   ```
7. Step 7.
   Change dbtype in **config.php** file  **C:\xampp\htdocs\moodle\config.php**
   `$CFG->dbtype    = 'mysql';`
                   Replace it with
           `$CFG->dbtype    = 'mariadb';`
8. Step 8.
       Execute the following query in phpmyadmin database one by one

   ```
   set Global innodb_file_format = Barracuda
   set Global innodb_file_per_table = 1
   set Global innodb_large_prefix = "ON"
   ```
9. Step 9.
       **Goto C:\Xampp\htdocs\moodle\admin\index.php**

   > line:712 Comment the following line LIKE THIS

`//redirect("index.php?sessionstarted=1&lang=$CFG->lang");`

```
        .............Done............
```